# What are the linear factors of $x^3 - 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

The polynomial is defined as $$x^3 - 2 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$$

How do you figure out the linear factors of the term? If I evaluate the function in polar coordinates I get some weird terms that can't possibly be correct. Wolfram says that I have to multiply the real solution by the third roots of $i$ (as that's the unity vector), but if I write those solutions as linear factors and multiply the term out I get something different from my polynomial.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Edit: My attempt at solving with polar coordinates: $$x^3 = 2 = 2+0i = 2(\cos(0) + i\sin(0))  | \sqrt[3]{}$$ $$x = \sqrt[3]{2}(\cos(L*\frac{2\pi}{3}) + i\sin(L*\frac{2\pi}{3}) | L \in \{0, 1, 2\}$$ $$x_1 = \sqrt[3]{2}$$ $$x_2 = \sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$ $$x_3 = \sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$

Comment: That should work.  Why not add your computations here so we can see what you did?

Comment: Couldn't factor this as a difference of cubes and then apply a quadratic formula on the remaining non-linear term to get all the factors?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy Added my attempt at solving the Problem.

Comment: @JB King I think that would only work if there wasn't a standalone number like there is here.

Comment: @Skydiver The product $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=x^2-3$, so you have it!

Comment: @Matthew Conroy Damn, you are right.   Made a mistake while initially calculating that I didn't do while typping out my approach. Oh well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See that any root that you could have of $x^3-2$ is of the style $\sqrt[3]{2}\ e^{2it\pi/3}$ with $t=0,1,2$, so it factors into

$$(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x-\sqrt[3]{2}\ e^{2i\pi/3})(x-\sqrt[3]{2}\ e^{4i\pi/3})$$

If you want to know what is $e^{2ti\pi/3}$ use the polar coordinates:

$$e^{2it\pi/3}=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{3}\right)$$

And all the roots are:

$$\sqrt[3]{2}\ e^{2i\pi/3}=\sqrt[3]{2}\left( \cos\left(\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)\right)=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

$$\sqrt[3]{2}\ e^{4i\pi/3}=\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi }{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi }{3}\right)\right)=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}--\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$